# Get value of property from an array of objects with childs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've an array of objects, and every object has his children, like this:

```
var array = [{
    name: "name",
    children: {
            name: "namename",
            children: {
                    name: "namenamename",
                    prop: "56"
            }
    },
    ...
 },
...
]
```

Now i want to get value of field 'prop', but i want to do this from main object, its children or children of children:

let's say i've function:

```
var get = function(obj) {
    ...
}
```

and i can send to this function:

```
get(array[0])
get(array[0].children[0])
get(array[0].children[0].children[0])
```

I dont want to write three functions for that, how can i do this with one get() function?

I want to get "prop" field from object, and "prop" for every child of child is the same. So in above example if i call function get() with

```
array[0] //or 
array[0].children //or 
array[0].children[0].children[0] //or 
array[0].children[1].children[0] //or 
array[0].children[0].children[1]
```

i should get always the same value of prop. I need to have function that will search in entire object, but i dont know if i call this function frm parent or its child or child of child

Comment: what do you do with more than one prop?

Comment: This one will be enough. Isn't it? `get(array[0].children.children)`

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy but i dont know if i will call this function from parent or its child.

Prop for every child in one object is the same, sorry for not mention that. So i can always take this from first child of child

Comment: So you mean your parent objects can also have a "prop" field? If so, your example code is incomplete

Comment: Your question is very vague. What exactly do you want to do? Get the last `children` instance in your object?

Comment: No, only child of child can have "prop" field, but i can send to function parent from whom i want to get "prop" of its child

Comment: Use lodash [get](https://lodash.com/docs#get) function: `_.get(array, '[0].children[0].children[0]', null);`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, that all `children` properties are arrays and all properties with a given name are collected, then this proposal should work.

```js
function getProp(array, prop) {
    var r = [];
    array.forEach(function (a) {
        if (prop in a) {
            r.push(a[prop]);
        }
        if (Array.isArray(a.children)) {
            r = r.concat(getProp(a.children, prop));
        }
    });
    return r;
}

var array = [{ name: "name", children: [{ name: "namename", children: [{ name: "namenamename", prop: "56" }] }] }],
    prop = getProp(array, 'prop');

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(prop, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```